# Minimal memory usage in topological sort

Tags: c, topological-sort

I'm writing a program for topological sorting of a directed graph.

Let the number of vertices be `V ≤ 2000`, and the number of edges equal to `E ≤ V * (V - 1) / 2`, then
the program must use less memory than `10 * V + 2 * E + 4Mb`.

I tried storing the graph as adjacency matrix and adjacency lists, but in both cases, when `V = 2000` and `E = 1999000`, my program was out of memory.

Tell me how best to store the graph so that memory usage is minimal.

[implementation via adjacency lists](https://pastebin.com/B1P42nwX)

[implementation via adjacency matrix](https://pastebin.com/2sMDWggr)

Comment: Memory usage should be minimal usually for adjacency lists (especially for graphs with large number of nodes).

Comment: '4Mb' stay for megabyte or megabit?

Comment: `10 * V + 2 * E + 4Mb` does not make any sense; it is a number plus a number of megabits. For example, if there are 10 vertices and 20 edges, it is 10 * 10 + 2 * 20 + 4 Mb, which is 100 + 200 + 4 Mb = 300 + 4 Mb. The 300 part is just a number, not an amount of memory. First, is that supposed to be megabytes (MB), not megabits (Mb)? And perhaps mebibytes (MiB, 1,048,576 bytes), not megabytes (MB, 1,000,000 bytes)? And are the 10 and 2 supposed to be numbers of bytes? So “10 bytes • V + 2 bytes • E + 4 MiB”?

Answer (score 2):

Given your memory use formula, you need to not use more than 2 bytes per edge, and not more than 10 bytes per vertex (except maybe for some small overhead that will fit in the 4Mb slop space).

Your adjacency list implementation stores the adjacency list as an array of pointers. That's not viable, since a pointer is 4 or more likely 8 bytes.
Index your vertices, and replace pointers to vertices with uint16_t (2 bytes).

The details:

- Store all edges in an array: `uint16_t edges[E];` All edges out of a particular vertex will be stored contiguously in this array. First edges out from the first vertex, then edges out from the second vertex and so on.
- Have an array of `uint32_t vertices[V][2];` for the vertices. The two values stored are an index into the edges array, and the number of edges out of this vertex.

It's easy to see that this uses 2E+8V bytes to represent your graph.

When you're running the toposort, you need a count per vertex (describing how many in-edges the vertex has remaining). Use an array `uint16_t in_count[V];` for this. `uint16_t` is again enough, since no vertex can have more than 1999 in-edges when `V<=2000`.

This uses an additional 2 bytes per vertex, giving a total of `2E+10V` as required.

Note that you can easily save 4 bytes per vertex by not storing the number of edges, and instead rely on the end-index for the edges for a particular vertex being the start-index for the next vertex. You'll have to add an extra index after the last vertex to mark the end of the final run of edges. I note that this is clever, but saves at most 8KB given V<=2000.

(You can also in principle save more by packing the data more tightly. 2000 < 10**11, so you can pack the edge length and vertex index data in 11 bits rather than in `uint16_t`. The code will start getting really ugly to access the data stored).

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the simplest solution to my problem.
I just started storing the graph as a bit array

```
Graph* createGraph(int V) {
    Graph* graph = malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    graph->V = V;
    graph->visited = (int*) calloc(V, sizeof(int));
    graph->adj = (unsigned char*) calloc(((V * V) / 8 + 1), sizeof(unsigned char));
    return graph;
}

void addEdge(Graph* graph, int src, int dest) {
    int newNode = src * graph->V + dest;
    graph->adj[newNode/8] |= (1 << newNode % 8);
}

void DFS(Graph* graph, int v, Stack* stack, Data data) {
    if (graph->visited[v] == 1) {
        fprintf(data.out, "impossible to sort");
        freeGraph(graph);
        freeStack(stack);
        shutdown(data);
    }

    if (graph->visited[v] == 0) {
        graph->visited[v] = 1;
        for(int u = 0; u < graph->V; u++) {
            int n = v * graph->V + u;
            if (graph->adj[n / 8] & (1 << n % 8))
                DFS(graph, u, stack, data);
        }
        graph->visited[v] = 2;
        push(stack, v);
    }
}
```